# RAM Upgrade on 2018 Mac mini

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini

I just purchased 64GB of RAM that's compatible with my 2018 Mac mini, but in no way shape or form do I trust myself enough to make the installation myself. I called my local Apple Store to see if they could do it for me, and they said they couldn't do it with third-party RAM for warranty reasons. Does anyone know of a place that could make the installation for me such as a place like Best Buy perhaps? Not really sure who does this type of stuff by I would definitely prefer to have a professional do it instead of risking messing something up on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Check your local area for Mac specialists. I found a tame Mac guy, after I attempted to install the RAM, but didn't seat it properly and broke my screwdriver in the process. He charged me £50, so on Crucial's prices I'm still making a massive saving on Apple's charge.

As a business, they'll be insured against damage.

Answer (score 0):

Apple trains and certifies people to do repairs globally. I wonder why they didn’t refer you here:

- https://locate.apple.com

It’s a delicate operation even for trained technicians and you move parts in small openings.